# How unmounting closes file descriptors?

Tags: osx, file-descriptors, unmounting

Checking currently open files on my `/Volumes/UNTITLED` gives me 2 entries:

```
$ sudo lsof /Volumes/UNTITLED/
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mds      62 root    8r   DIR    1,6    32768    2 /Volumes/UNTITLED
mds      62 root   19r   DIR    1,6    32768    2 /Volumes/UNTITLED
$
```

When I run [`diskutil unmountDisk disk2`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html), all descriptors are successfully closed (e.g. I cannot do `lsof /Volumes/UNTITLED/` anymore, since the folder is gone).

**What exactly `diskutil unmountDisk` does to close file descriptors?** Can I close file descriptors myself?

As far as I understand `diskutil` is closed source. Can the question be answered by taking `umount`?

**Agenda**

Basically I'm trying to understand how to tell a process close a given file descriptor, e.g. emulate what unmount does.

I think telling the process to close a file descriptor should be illegal, as generally it can easily cause process to crash. However *I think* `diskutil unmountDisk` somehow manages to gently asks `mds` to no longer possess the file.

I'm curious if I can ask gently too. I know there's a `endfsent` OS function, but it's not a program, I cannot run it to manipulate file descriptors open by different processes.

Comment: Just because `lsof` can't list them anymore by path, doesn't mean they're closed. I'd guess they're still open, but all reads and writes to them return errors.  `mds` may also close them on unmount...

Comment: Good point @derobert. Do you know if I could look anywhere for those errors, like some system log?

Comment: They'd be returned to each process directly, and only logged if that process decided to. Not sure if OS X has some method to observe them otherwise (I'm not really that familiar with OS X).

Comment: I don't know how OSX works, but based on my general understanding of how OSes work, the most plausible way this works is that `diskutil` talks to `mds` and either `mds` does the unmounting or `mds` closes the volumes and then signals that it's ok to unmount. The theory that the file descriptors in `mds` are somehow closed from the outside sounds extremely strange. You aren't looking for a way to get a program to close a file descriptor, you're looking for the way `mds` learns about unmount requests.